print pattern right hand pyramid using 2D array
I wanted to print a 2D array matrix with a pattern (right half pyramid) and each position will store a number that will increase as the position change.
I created the pattern using a 2D array and assigned an integer value to each position which should increase as the position changes but some positions have a 0 value.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] twoD = new int[4][4];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                twoD[i][i] = k;
                k++;
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }


Output :- 
0 
0 2 
0 0 5 
0 0 0 9 

Expected Output:-
0
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9


Check the indexing on your 2D array. I believe you typed i when you meant to type j.
